# Why is multicolumn index not used even though I have all indexed columns used in query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created an index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_prog_time ON program (startTime, endTime);
```

But in my query, even though I have a `WHERE` on both `startTime` and `endTime`, it appears the index is not used (index shown in possible keys but not keys)?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT prog.id
FROM program prog
WHERE prog.asset IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(a.id)
    FROM asset a
    INNER JOIN assetpackage ap
    ON ap.asset = a.id
    INNER JOIN package p
    ON p.id = ap.package
    INNER JOIN component c
    ON c.package = p.id
    INNER JOIN provision pr
    ON pr.component = c.id
    INNER JOIN transaction t
    ON pr.transaction = t.id
    WHERE prog.startTime < '2018-04-24 17:30:00'
    AND prog.endTime > '2018-04-24 17:30:00'
    AND p.archived = 0
    AND p.serviceNo IS NOT NULL
    AND t.user = 111
    AND pr.startAt < '2018-04-24 17:30:00'
    AND pr.endAt > '2018-04-24 17:30:00'
);
```

The explain output

[image]

Notice the 1st row

Comment: You might try changing the 1st 2 parts of your where to use between, but I suspect that may not help. IOW ```'2018-04-24 17:30:00' BETWEEN prog.startTime AND prog.endTime```

Comment: @SloanThrasher thanks for the suggestion, but you are right, it does not help me use the index

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join instead of an in clause

```
SELECT prog.id
FROM program prog
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.id  as my_id
    FROM asset a
    INNER JOIN assetpackage ap
    ON ap.asset = a.id
    INNER JOIN package p
    ON p.id = ap.package
    INNER JOIN component c
    ON c.package = p.id
    INNER JOIN provision pr
    ON pr.component = c.id
    INNER JOIN transaction t
    ON pr.transaction = t.id
    AND p.archived = 0
    AND p.serviceNo IS NOT NULL
    AND t.user = 111
    AND pr.startAt < '2018-04-24 17:30:00'
    AND pr.endAt > '2018-04-24 17:30:00'
) T on T.my_id = prog.asset 
WHERE prog.startTime < '2018-04-24 17:30:00'
  AND prog.endTime > '2018-04-24 17:30:00'
```

Comment: This does not appear to change the explain output? I do need to move the `prog.startTime` WHERE clause out.

Comment: the use of inner join instead of the In clause should change the perfomance .

Comment: .  anyway answer  updated .. with  where clause applied to progr externally

Answer (score 0):

Because there are other columns(like `t.user`, `p.archived` etc) as well in your where condition before indexed column.

Order of the columns in where query also matters.

Try filtering only `startAt` and `endAt` column.

https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys

Comment: I think you are looking at the wrong column? The index I want to use is for `prog.startTime` and `prog.endTime` which are at the start of the WHERE. Its a good point tho.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has pretty good [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on multi-column indexes.

The answer to your question is that you are using inequalities on the two fields.  So, MySQL evaluates the conditions in your query, comparing to the columns -- in order -- in the index.  The first column is `startTime` and it has an inequality comparison.  So, MySQL never compares the second column.

This question is about why a particular query doesn't use a particular index, and that has been answered multiple times.

It is not clear what the best approach is for your query.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, providing sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what your query is doing.